# When and how can I use an Entity created in a use case X' sequence inside another use case Y' sequence?

Tags: uml, software-design, use-case, sequence-diagram, system-design

I have a use case X' sequence in which I create an Entity Z.
I have another use case Y' sequence where I want to use the SAME already created Entity Z.

How to do that? Do I have to specify it in some way?

For example, if use case X' sequence ends in a Window W Boundary and  sequence of use case Y starts with Window W Boundary, can I just assume (inside use case Y sequence diagram) that Entity Z (that I didn't destroy in use case X) is available in use case Y?

**Other question, if I want to do a ref (so an include), how to "pass" the Entity Z to the ref'd use case?**

Comment: Uses cases are not functions that pass variables. You are probably trying to use the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @GeertBellekens these are sequence diagrams, is it wrong to pass things/entity in sequence diagrams?

Comment: Sequence diagrams are not use cases. You are probably doing functional decomposition. That is not what uses cases are meant for.

Comment: @GeertBellekens I know that sequence diagrams are not use cases... I just don't know if in sequence diagrams should pass Entity to other ref'd use cases.

Comment: If you know that they are different then why do you use the wrong words? Also do not ask two questions in one thread.

Answer (score 4):

I understand from your question that you are using sequence diagrams to describe use cases. Nothing wrong with that.

When you create something in one use case that is later needed in another use case, that doesn’t mean there is a formal connection between the two use cases. The precondition of the second use case is simply that this object exists. It doesn’t need to know, where it comes from. This precondition can be explicit or implicit by just using the object.

The situation is different, when you are including or extending use cases. If such use cases are described with sequence diagrams it becomes necessary to map the lifelines in one interaction to the ones in the other one. This can be done with parameters.

Of course, such formality is often not required. You can simply have the convention to use the same names. Also «include» and «extend» should be used wisely. It is not the goal to make a sophisticated use case diagram, but to understand the uses of the system.

Comment: _sophisticated use case diagram_ is better know as _functional decomposition_ and wrong per se. Once on a seminar I heard "if your UC diagrams look like spider webs your design is broken". Honestly, I don't think the OP got the gist of UC synthezation. Once again a good answer - to a bad quetion.

Comment: Yes, I agree, very often such a diagram is a sign of functional decomposition, which is not the purpose of use case analysis. It cannot be stated often enough.